# How to prevent compromising user credentials on a OAUTH native application

Tags: native, oauth-2.0, keylogger

I read the entire OAUTH 2.0 RFP document and I am little confused.

Say I develop native IOS application and I want to use my user credentials to authorize it to access my facebook account.

What is the best practice to prevent credentials compromising?

I mean, what is the problem for a simple keylogger to log the user and password which are typed to the facebook authentication page?

Am I missing something?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> what is the problem for a simple keylogger to log the user and password which are typed to the facebook authentication page?

Theoretically?  Nothing.

> Am I missing something?

Yes...  You are missing the global consideration/concern...   Username/password security is only as strong as the system using them to authenticate.  It is your trust in the client/system that is the determining factor here...

The point of OAuth is to grant third party applications limited access to resources - which can also be used for SSO authentication..

To use Facebook in an iPhone app for SSO, your app transfers/redirects the user to the Facebook app.  The Facebook app handles authentication and then returns/redirects the user back to your app with an authentication token (auth token).   If the user is already logged in to Facebook and has already authorized your app, this essentially happens in the background.

The point being that the responsibility for authentication is transferred to the Facebook app.   If the system is compromised, the leak would primarily occur outside of your app and in the Facebook app...  But this again points to a larger issue - the security and credibility of the system - if its compromised, its compromised.

> What is the best practice to prevent credentials compromising?

Just understand that an auth_token is essentially the same as a username/password combination.  With iPhone you probably will not have a need to store it (instead just utilize the Facebook instance),  however, if for some reason you do need to store the information – secure it.

From a more global perspective?   - Only supply your username and password to/on systems you trust (no brainer).